# VIM gets stuck when I try to type a parenthesis ( or when the cursor is ahead or on a parenthesis

Tags: restructuredtext, macvim

I recently met with this weird issue when I edit rst file using VIM on macOS Catalina 10.15.7:

When I try to type a parenthesis

> (

or when my cursor tries to pass the parenthesis, VIM will get stuck and then the CPU fan of my laptop will run crazy.
I finally figured out this issue happened after I created a **~/.vimrc** file  and set

> syntax on

If I delete this file, this issue will disappear.

Does anyone know why this happens? And how to fix this issue meanwhile keeping VIM recognize all kinds of syntax?

Comment: I found same issue when using MAC terminal ...

Comment: Is there a solution to this yet? I get the same issue when running vi installed with git-bash on Windows. I have no plugins installed and just a very basic vimrc with syntax enable turned on. The file I'm working on is about 21,000 lines of code, but vi is supposed to work with that well....